# How do I force the ICS browser to finish syncing bookmarks?

Tags: sync, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, stock-browser

I have a brand new Acer A200, and I upgraded it to ICS (4.0.3). I set up sync with my Chrome bookmarks, but it's been a few hours now and it doesn't seem to be finishing the sync - I've got the complete folder structure of the bookmarks on my PCs, but most of the folders are empty. Is there anything that I can do to force it to finish the job?

Comment: I seem to recall that taking a long time, too.  Eventually it worked; but then it started showing a "sync error".  I simply disabled Browser, and am instead using https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome which works surprisingly well. It also seems to sync _more_ bookmarks than the stock Browser did.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the moment I'm not coming up with any solution, so I've up and bought [ChromeMarks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.h.chromemarks&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5oLmNocm9tZW1hcmtzIl0.). I went for the pay version because I REALLY wanted to manipulate the bookmarks on the device. If you just need to see them on the device, then the free version ([ChromeMarks Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.h.chromemarks.lite&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5oLmNocm9tZW1hcmtzLmxpdGUiXQ..)) does a fine job.

I have no idea what the real problem was, but it was worth $1.99 to me to have it solved immediately (especially since the Browser's built-in bookmarks can't be viewed in any kind of list mode - just the icon view).